# Position fixed and width 25% not taking correct width

Tags: html, css, position, width, css-position

I have two divs. outer div taking 25%. And the inner div is placed at the bottom (`position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 25%; border-top: 1px solid red`) But this is not taking 25%.

I am adding border for this div. So there is an white space is showing because of the width.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-div">
    <div id="outer-div">
        <div id="div-1"></div>
        <div id="div-2">
            <div id="inner-div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#outer-div {
    width: 100%;
}
#div-1, #div-2 {
    width: 100%;
}
#inner-div {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; width: 25%; 
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

How to apply exactly apply 25% width to `inner-div` which has position fixed ?

**UPDATE** Added js fiddle in comment

Comment: This seems to be working fine. Can you make a fiddle where it is not?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uur2h5w3/3/

Outer div and inner div has 25% width but inner div seems it has more width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css for this

```
#inner-div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uur2h5w3/5/)

Comment: I don't think that this matters as he has not set any side borders for the `<div>`

Comment: can you please share any fiddle link so we can identify the actual problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uur2h5w3/3/

Outer div and inner div has 25% width but inner div seems it has more width.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your body margin . This issue because of you don't remove your body `margin` you can simply fix this

```
body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
#main-div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    }
#outer-div {
    width: 100%;
    }
#div-1, #div-2 {
    width: 100%;
    }
#inner-div {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; width: 25%; 
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main-div">
  <div id="outer-div">
    <div id="div-1"></div>
    <div id="div-2">
      <div id="inner-div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason why `inner-div` has more width than `outer-div` is because `inner-div` has `position: fixed` applied to it. 
Now when you apply `position: fixed`, it makes the element position relative to the viewport.

So, in this case `inner-div` is relative to the `body` which has some user-agent margin styles applied. To make them have same width apply `margin: 0` to the body.

Also, apply `box-sizing: border-box` to `outer-div` to exclude the border in the width.

I have updated the fiddle for you. So both divs have the same width.

https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/uur2h5w3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position is relative to the browser window hence percentage values will be relative to the <html> element (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp). Although experimental [position:sticky](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) might accomplish what you need since it is relative to the viewport (parent relative element).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset body for browser. For this reason "inner-div" is taking space.

body{margin:0;padding:0;}

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
#main-div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
     background: blue none repeat scroll 0 0;
     border: 1px solid blue;
}
#outer-div {
    width: 25%;
   border: 1px solid green;
}
#div-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
#div-2 {
   display: table;
    height: 0;
    padding-right: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
#inner-div {
  text-align: center;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 25%; 
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-div">
    <div id="outer-div"> //list
        <div id="div-1"> //parent-scrol
        <div id="div-2"> //scroll
            <div id="div-3"> //inner-list
              <div id="inner-div">wefffef</div> //create-new
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```